# Allow all inbound traffic from specific IP addresses

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, tcpip

I am running one of our server applications on Windows 7 and I'm having trouble with the firewall. The application receives various events over TCP from a network device but the connection port varies for each new connection.

I need the Windows firewall to be turned on for obvious security but I want to be able to create a rule that allows all traffic originating from a single IP address through. I can't find an obvious way to create a rule to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to your firewall through the `Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall`. Once on that screen you will look to the left hand pane and select the `Advanced Settings`. After that, right click on the `Inbound Rules` and select `New Rule...` Make sure you select the `Custom Rule`. Now go through the wizard and on the 4th screen it will provide a screen to limit via IP address in the Scope screen. Hopefully that is what you need. Just complete the rest of the wizard out and you should be all set.

I would provide screenshots, but I don't have that privilege yet...  :(

Comment: I was sure I'd tried that before and it didn't work but I was clesarly wrong so thanks!